# Django translation from database

Tags: django, translation

I have got strings in my data base that I need to translate so that the user can see it in the language of their choice. I am unsure on how to go about doing this.

In my template I have:

```
{% for author, titleList in authorTitle.items %}
    <h2>"{{author}}"</h2>
    {% for title in titleList %}
        <p>"{{title}}"</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And in my `views.py` I have:

```
authorList = list(TblBooks.objects.values_list("authorid__authorname", flat = True).distinct())
authorBook = {} 
for author in authorList:
    authorBook[author] = TblBooks.objects.filter(authorid__authorname = author).order_by("title")
return render(request, 'index.html', {  'authorTitle': authorBook } )
```

Is there any way to translate the title either from the views or the template. If not, how do I go about translating the titles?

Comment: You will have to add translations for the titles manually. Django translations are for strings only. For the stuff you wanna do try django-hvad.